# Relationship between two types of users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

What is the best way to create relationship  between two types of users. I have users that are supervisors to workers (currently have a role enum set to supervisor or worker in User model). So each worker must have a supervisor and the supervisor can have many workers (may not have any). There are other kind of users but for now I just need to set/get each worker's supervisor. Do I need a has_many :through or simply create a supervisor_id attribute on User and set to a user_id of a user who has a role of supervisor?

Answer (score 1):

A `has_many :through` is another way to make a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. If each worker can have multiple supervisors, then yes, I'd go with that. If they can only have one supervisor, then a simple `supervisor_id` would work.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Since a worker can only one supervisor, I just added a supervisor_id and followed the example at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations. Here is the code: <code>has_many :subordinates, class_name: "User",
                          foreign_key: "supervisor_id"
 
  belongs_to :supervisor, class_name: "User"</code>

Comment: That code looks good. If that does work out, accept and up-vote the answer so others can see it.

Comment: No problem. You still should mark it as answered, though (click the check-mark).